# How to dynamically generate div containing all the elements on each click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am trying to generate div dynamically using below code, but the new div doesn't contain the elements of my existing div container.

```
Below is the code which I tried:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/bvb7msne/2/

How can we dynamically create all the elements of my inner div (all from both inner1 and inner2 divs) into the newly generated one without writing append function for each element that is there in existing div, what am I missing there?

Also, how to delete the div which got newly created using button click ?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    div = document.createElement('div');
    $(div).addClass("inner").html("new inner div");
    $("#container").append(div);
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.inner1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #808080;
  background-color: #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: green;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner">
            <div class="inner1">
                <section>
                    Enter Name:<input type="text" /><br /><br />
                    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Colorful_Parrots_Couple.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
                </section>
            </div>
        <div class="inner2">
            <section>
                Enter Name:<input type="text" /><br /><br />
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Colorful_Parrots_Couple.jpg" width="200" height="200" />                
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="add">Add DIV</button>
```

Comment: Come on and post the code in here instead of using a hack to post the JSFiddle link. Stackoverflow has snipplets which is just like using JSFiddle.

Comment: Hi, added the code.. please check it out

Comment: @SathishPanduga does the answer meets your requirement?

Comment: Hi Anoop, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .clone() for this,

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    $("#container").append($(".inner").clone());
});
$("#remove").click(function () {
    $("#container .inner:last").remove();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bvb7msne/7/)

1. `clone()` will return a copy of the specified element
2. `append()` will add an element as the last child of specified parent element.
3. `remove()` will delete the specified element from dom

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/bvb7msne/5/) from your jsfiddle.

```
$(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            $(div).addClass("inner").html($('.inner').clone());
            $("#container").append(div);
        });
    });
```

Also you can do like this:

```
$(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {
            $("#container").append(
                $('<div>').addClass('inner').html($('.inner').clone())
            );

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#add").click(
        function () {
            $("#container").append($(".inner").html());
        }
    );
});
```

You can select the parent element that holders the inner1 and inner2 elements. Then use the html function to get all the html within that element and pass it to the append function being called on the element you are attempting to populate.